# Who am I? Not Basil Seeds, Lime, or a Well

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

It has black, but it is not [Basil Seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basil),

It has white but it's not [Lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limestone),

It has water but it is not a [Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_well),

It has feathers but it is not a bird

> Who am I?

Hint:

> It comes in pair

Hint 2:

> It is a body part.

Comment: Is it `pbpbahg`? http://www.rot13.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you

> Eyes

It has black, but it is not Basil Seeds,

> Pupil of eye

It has white but it's not Lime,

> sclera of eye

It has water but it is not a Well,

> Tears in eyes or general tear layer to protect eye.

It has feathers but it is not a bird

> eye lashes?? not sure of this.

Hint

> Eyes come in pair in an ideal world.

Finally got spoiler tag to work without copypasting >! from other pages.

Edit: Changes -

> Iris replaced by Pupil on correct suggestion of  Nic Hartley, appreciate it-Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What about

> A picture of Swan lake

It has black, but it is not Basil Seeds,

> The Black Swan

It has white but it's not Lime,

> The White Swans

It has water but it is not a Well,

> It's a lake

It has feathers but it is not a bird

> Swan has feathers and is a bird, but a painting is not a bird

Comment: I have added the Hint :)

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth I've a feeling you're referring to the eye - I didn't put that as an answer and in case it's the right one - it's not entirely black, more like brown, and the feathers... i would say fur instead

Comment: You're right :)

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth Someone actually put it as an answer - you can check accept.  Also some tips for the riddle - generally it's a hint that the riddle is too broad if you have to add hints to narrow it down.  Most of the answers here (including Will smith ~~) fits as an answer before the hints.  However don't let that keeps you away from creating more fun riddle!

Answer (score 4):

a half-joking, half-serious answer:

> [William Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_and_feathers#Coming_of_the_American_Revolution)

Comment: HAHAHA :D I wish you were right :)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a long stretch, but you are:

> [Comaster schlegelii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comaster_schlegelii)

Explanation:

> It is a bushy feather star, with white and black feathers.

Comment: I have added the Hint :)

Answer (score 1):

You are

> River

It has black:

> [Blackwater river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackwater_river)

It has white:

> [Whitewater river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewater_river_(river_type))

It has water

> It is a river, so it has water

It has feathers

> [Feather river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather_River)

Comment: I have added the Hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Before the hint, I thought it was

> a fishing fly, like the [Triumph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_fly#/media/File:ClassicTriumphBassFly.jpg)
>   it has black, it has white
>   it has water (where it fishes)
>   it is made with feathers, but is not a bird